# How to stop synchronized methods from deadlocking

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, volatile, synchronized

If we had a synchronized method that would need to be synchronized just if the same object is used, how would it be done?

For example, we had a `transferMoney()` synchronized function that could be parallelly executed if all parameters are different in different calls, but not if a parameter in call one is same as parameters in call two:

```
public synchronized transferMoney(Account a, Account b, float value){
    synchronized(a){
        synchronized(b){
            transfer();
        }
    }
}
```

How would we stop a deadlock here if the function was called at the same time for `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`?

I thought about `a` and `b` being volatile, or synchronizing based of hash-value of `a` and `b`, or by new object which would contain `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

> How would we stop a deadlock here if the function was called at the same time for `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`?

That's a scenario of catastrophe if there's a possibility for one thread to enter synchronized blocks in the reversed order relatively to another thread.

To avoid deadlocks, there should be the same order of monitor-objects in **every** method. To ensure that, you need to have a uniform logic of ordering the monitor objects based on their unique properties (and not on the order of the method arguments). I.e. to guaranty a consistent ordering, you need to decide which of the arguments should be used in the first synchronized section and which in the second.

Assuming that account looks like that:

```
public class Account {
    public static final BinaryOperator<Account> FIRST = 
        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Account::getId));
    
    public static final BinaryOperator<Account> SECOND =
        BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Account::getId));
    private UUID id;
    // other properties and methods
}
```

That's how `transfer()` method should look like:

```
public void transferMoney(Account a, Account b, float value) {
    Account first = Account.FIRST.apply(a,b);
    Account second = Account.SECOND.apply(a,b);
    
    synchronized (first) {
        synchronized (second) {
            transfer();
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative to using `synchronized` and monitor-objects would be to use [Locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html). The core idea remains the same: there should be no possibility for a thread to acquire one lock and wait for another lock indefinitely, instead such thread should release the lock it has acquired if it can't get all the locks needed to perform the action.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? How would that look and work?

Comment: @Stupidquestion010 You should stick with the **same order** of *monitor-objects* in **all** your methods. In you have `synchronized (a) { synchronized (b) { // do things } }`, there **shouldn't** be a method with `synchronized (b) { synchronized (a) { // do things } }`. Choose one, or another. If there is **no** possibility for different treads to enter synchronized sections against different monitors and block each other, you'll be fine.

Comment: I guess the issue is that the caller could switch the order. The general solution is to define an intrinsic ordering in your logic before locking. For example, you could always lock the account with the smaller account number first.